# Validating Phone Number With RegExp Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, dojo

I have a [function](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/B3d9R/7/) which validates the phone number entered by the user using **regexp**. However it does not seem to evaluate *true* even though the **regexp** is correct. I am not sure what i am doing incorrectly.

**Html**

```
<body class="claro">
    <form id="myform" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form">

    <input
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
        data-dojo-props="
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Invalid Phone Number !',
            missingMessage: 'Phone Number Required !'"
        id="phone" title="Phone Number"
    placeholder="Your Phone Number"
  onkeydown="validatePhoneNumberFormat()"/>

    </form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
  //test phone number 188-123-1234
    function validatePhoneNumberFormat(){
     var phoneNumber = dijit.byId("phone");
        var phoneFormat = new RegExp('^[0-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$');
        phoneNumber.validator = function(value){
          console.log(value);
          console.log(phoneFormat.test(value.trim()));
          return phoneFormat.test(value.trim());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Argh! Don't force a specific formatting. Strip out all the characters which aren't significant (so keep numbers and `+` (and hopefully that's all you need)) and then test the bits that actually matter. (My number, BTW, has 12 digits in it, so you should probably rethink your idea about what constitutes a phone number anyway)

Comment: Be sure that your use case is limited to only a particular geographic area and certain numbers as this kind of hard coding is not good for localization or optional area codes.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
  function validatePhoneNumberFormat(){
     var phoneNumber = dijit.byId("phone");
        var phoneFormat = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
        phoneNumber.validator = function(value){
          console.log(value);
          console.log(phoneFormat.test(value.trim()));
          return phoneFormat.test(value.trim());

        }

    }
```

***REGEX EXPLANATION***

```
/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d{3}»
   Exactly 3 times «{3}»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d{3}»
   Exactly 3 times «{3}»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d{4}»
   Exactly 4 times «{4}»
Assert position at the very end of the string «$»
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to double escape `\d` inside `RegExp` constructor, so use this:

```
var phoneFormat = new RegExp('^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$');
```

Or else use regex literal:

```
var phoneFormat = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
```

Since `RegExp` takes a string as an argument you need to double escape all the special meta characters as one escape is used for String and second is for regex engine.

Comment: Using a regex literal would be a nicer approach than fixing the constructor function approach.

Comment: Why `[0-9]\d{2}` instead of `\d{3}`?

Comment: @Tuga: Yes `\d{3}` makes more sense, I just highlighted main problem in OP's code, didn't tinker the regex (editing now).

Comment: @anubhava +1 for the double escape catch.